# Switching between two images that have a single HTML file

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I have a top navbar that is common to two webpages, my root URL (/) and firstpage (/firstpage).
In the top navbar there is are 2 image and I want to switch between those images based on the page the user is on.
Code is as follows:

```
<img class="dark" src="/images/icons/IMAGE_home.png">
<img class="light" src="/images/icons/IMAGE1_page2.png">
```

When the user is on homepage, he should see the first image and the second should be hidden. When the user is on the second page, he should see the second image and the first should be hidden.

Any css/angular/javascript tricks to accomplish this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A class on the homepage body element, plus CSS to set the `display` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically something like this would be done with a back-end script, but it's certainly possible with JavaScript and CSS.

First, set **both** images to be hidden by default:

```
.light, .dark {
  display: none;
}
```

Second, you would need to get the page name from the URL by checking `window.location`:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var page = path.split("/").pop();
```

Then you would need check against the current page in a condition:

```
if (page == 'firstpage') {
   document.getElementsByClassName("light")[0].style.display = 'block';
}
else {
  document.getElementsByClassName("dark")[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

In the above example, `/firstpage` will have `IMAGE1_page2.png`, while every other page will have `IMAGE_home.png`. The root (just a trailing slash) can be checked against with `if (page) {}`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (location.pathname == "/firstpage") {
        $(".light").hide();
        $(".dark").show();
    } else {
        $(".dark").hide();
        $(".light").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: /firstpage will show "IMAGE1_page2.png" while all other pages will revert to the other image.